# Changes to code are only showing up in vs code viewer and not chrome

Tags: html, css

The hover feature on my button stopped working when I launched it in chrome. It works in fire fox but was wondering on how I can make my code more user friendly between browsers.

```css
a:link,
a:visited {
  background-color: #433966;
  border: 5px solid #5d596a;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px rgba(65, 62, 62, 0.2);
  color: rgb(205, 187, 162);
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 14px 25px;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Optima;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:link:hover {
  color: #433966;
  background-color: rgb(205, 187, 162)
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container" class="button" class=a:link:hover>
    <a href="information.html">Portfolio</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Have you checked if any other style is not overriding it?

Comment: Is this a cacheing issue?